# HTML livestream from IP Camera on ipod touch

Tags: javascript, html, ios, camera

At the moment I try to get the stream of my ip camera on my website.

Now I have this code snipped:

```html
document.write('<img id="camera" width="' + view_w + '" height="' + view_h + '" src="http://192.168.1.195/GetData.cgi?CH=1" alt="Die Verbindung wurde unterbrochen. Bitte warten..."</img>');
```

This snipped works (I see the livestream). But now the problem...
When I open the page with the `IE`, it works well with **no delay**, but if I open it with `Safari` I have an **delay of 2 seconds**.

Im using a ip camera from `Lupus Electronics` (Lupusnet LE934).

It's in a local network (192.168.1.xxx) **=** no connection to the internet.

Here is an Screenshot from the ip camera software, where I can set the settings:

[image]

Well. Now the 2 questions:

How can I reduce the delay (for Safari)?

Is the format `JPEG` or `H.264` better for **Safari**?

Comment: I would say `H.264` is better because `<video>` elements need this encoding format for Safari to load videos.

Comment: @AdamAzad i tried it multiple times, but the delay is still there.